# js Посчитать сумму столбцов в таблице

Tags: javascript

Собственно считаю вот так

```
var table = document.getElementById("table-id1");
let lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++) {
  let row = table.rows[i];
  for (var j = 1; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
    let cel = row.cells[j];

    lastRow.cells[j].innerText =
      (Number(lastRow.cells[j].innerText) || 0) +
      (Number(cel.innerText) || 0);
  }
}
```

Но на странице есть ещё одна таблица с table-id2, как мне для неё тоже считать сумму столбцов?
Вот так не работает

```
var table = document.getElementById("table-id2");
let lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length - 1; i++) {
  let row = table.rows[i];
  for (var j = 1; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
    let cel = row.cells[j];

    lastRow.cells[j].innerText =
      (Number(lastRow.cells[j].innerText) || 0) +
      (Number(cel.innerText) || 0);
  }
}
```

Таблицы одинаковые, вот одна из них

```
<table id="table-id2" class="table table-bordered">
 
    <thead>
 
    {% for start1, start2, start3 in table3 %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ start1 }}</th>
        <th>{{ start2 }}</th>
        <th>{{ start3 }}</th>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    {% for start1, start2, start3 in table4 %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ start1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ start2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ start3 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя для переменной let надо было поменять, всё заработало

```
let lastRow = table.rows[table.rows.length - 1];
```